# Получить список файлов из директории database/seed в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть ли получше способ получить список файлов из директории `database/seed`, чем этот:

```
$files = array_diff(scandir(__DIR__), array('..', '.', 'data'));
```

Можно ли достать только php-файлы из этого каталога? Просто там уже есть каталог `data`.

Comment: А чем плох этот способ?

Comment: этот код будет выполнять постоянно во время команды php artisan db:seed, и возможно будут проблемы если например добавить новый каталог туда

Answer (score 1):

В ларавеле для работы с файлами есть фасад `Storage`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$files = Storage::files($directory); // Все файлы в указанном каталоге

$files = Storage::allFiles($directory); // Все файлы и подкаталоги
```

[Ссылка](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#directories) на документацию

Comment: Storage::files('/'); выдаёт файлы, которые расположены в storage/app

Comment: @АйратИсмагилов, в чем проблема указать новый каталог? Тот что вам нужен, чтобы выводился!

Answer (score 0):

Для Storage можно указать свой путь в файле filesystems.php

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),  // этот путь надо заменить
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```